# Basic linear graph with label x & y intercept

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to graph a basic linear graph (y = 2x - 4).

I also want to have an x & y axis and for the x & y intercept to be circled (can be manually done).

I tried searching Stackexchange, but I couldn't find something like it.

Ultimately I would like for it to look like:

[image]

I did attempt it (but it is not quite what I'm looking for).

What I attempted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-10:10,
    samples=101,
   grid=both,
    smooth,
    no markers,
    ]
    \addplot {2*x-4};
        \node[label={180:{(0,-4)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:0,-4) {};
        \node[label={180:{(2,0)}},circle,fill,inner sep=2pt] at (axis cs:2,0) {};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

This code would produce:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \begin{axis}[x=1cm,y=1cm,
            axis lines = middle,
            xlabel = {$x$},
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=-1, xmax=5.2,
            ymin=-6.1, ymax=3.1,small,
            grid]
            
            % Plot 1
            \addplot [
            domain = -1:5,
            samples = 1000,blue,very thick] {2*x-4} 
            node [pos=.65, right] {\bfseries $y=2x-4$};
            \filldraw (2,0) circle(2pt);
            \draw[thin] (2,0) circle(.2) node[red,right, yshift=.2cm] {\; x-intercept (2,0)};
            \filldraw (0,-4) circle(2pt);
            \draw[thin] (0,-4) circle(.2) node[red,right] {\quad y-intercept (0,-4)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. One thing though if I wanted to cut the label " node [pos=.65, right] {\bfseries $y=2x-4$};" and then if I run it-- it won't work. Like If I want everything, but the equation to be depicted how would I go about. Thanks so much! @RaffaeleSantoro

Comment: No, it works, dont forghet the final ';'.
\addplot [
   domain = -1:5,
   samples = 1000,blue,very thick] {2*x-4};

Comment: Like if works. In its current form. But if my preference is to remove the equation label it won't work. The work around I noticed is if I change .65 to a bigger number like 1 then it won't appear.

Comment: Yes it dont appear because it goes outside the visible straight line. But it does work if you cancel them from the code. Oterwise put an empy string inside {}.